# Unable to start container process: exec: "npm run start" executable file not found in $PATH unknown

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an application that I have containerized.
This is its Dockefile:

```
FROM front-end-base:latest
COPY ... /app/...
...
EXPOSE 5000
RUN cd /app
CMD ["npm run start"]
```

The front-end-base has Node, NPM, Yarn and a few other packages installed.
The dockerfile copies the app's files over, uses yarn to install them from a yarn.lock, exposes the port, and then uses npm to start the application.

However, I get the following error:

```
"Failed to run image. Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container' - fail to create task for container: fail to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: unable to start container process exec: "npm run start": executable file not found in $PATH unknown
```

My ultimate goal is to get this working in a Docker Dev environment. However, I get the above error from command line, GUI running the image, and from the create Dev Environment process.

However, if I take the final image and instead of trying to run the app just bash into it via

```
docker run -it fe-test:latest /bin/bash -l
```

The container starts successfully, and I am able to navigate to the /app directory and executable "npm run start" successfully with no errors.

I have found several other people online asking semi-related questions but the answers have either not worked for me or not been relevant to my situation.

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: You're running `"npm run start"` as a single word, with spaces as part of the command; you're getting the same error as if you had run `"npm run start"` with the quotes in a shell.  Break that up into three words in the `CMD` array.

Comment: @DavidMaze Unfortunately I tried that as well, and got the same error. 

I have done some additional digging and it is because I used brew to install npm/nodejs and instead of installing it on the path it is installed in some brew home directory, creating a system link or direct referencing it fixed this error.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem shortly after posting.

Due to the way I installed npm/node/yarn (via a brew installation) to applications were not located at /usr/bin/npm but at a home directory under brew.

This is why it was complaining they were not on the path, either directly referencing the full path (which npm), or creating a system link will fix the problem.